# swift ошибка с UILabel

Tags: xcode, swift

Добрый вечер всем.

у меня вот такого плана ошибка, (че я не так зделал не понимаю)

вообщем обьявил я UILabel и прикрутил его как IBAOutlet

даю ему значение, а он выдает фатальную ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую ошибку? Как Вы задаете значение?

Comment: кто и когда вызывает функцию setVariableElement?

Comment: решил проблему !

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена. Дело все в том, что когда я нахожусь в TableViewController'e в списке елементов и выбираю какой то элемен, то срабатывает

```
    // метод который определяется перед переходом
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // куда мы направляемся
    if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? showCellController {

        let element = "\(sender)"

        print("element to send: \(element)")

        controller.text = element as String


        //controller.setVariable(element)

    }
}
```

который вызывает другой класс который подвязан под другой контроллер в котором находиться тот лейбл, а так, как IBA Outlet еще не объявлен хотя сам класс уже объявлен выдает ошибку.

Решение сперва создать переменную в которую сложиться данные, а потом через ViewDidLoad() вызвать метод который изначально нужно было вызвать и дать оутлету стринговое значение.